# Get replies from tweet (Python)

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I need to get all or at least a minumum number of replies from a specific tweet.

Using python I've tried **Tweepy**, but works in this way:

```
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:' + name, result_type='recent', include_entities=True).items()
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        tweet = c.next()
        if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
            if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == tweet_id:
                replies.append(tweet)
```

For example for a tweet of 1 year ago, it will last maybe days to get maybe 4 or 5 comments since it starts to search chronologically all tweets related to that account (*name*).

Then, I tried **Twarc**, but this library gets only the replies of the last week, so useless for tweets older than a week.

```
twarc replies 824077910927691778 > replies.json
```

Do you have any ideas for getting these comments?

Thanks in advance for who will help me.

Comment: Hello, Did you find an answer for this question?